# private field in object doesn't compile

Tags: eclipse, scala

I tried to run one example from Programming in Scala but compiler gives me error:

`Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
illegal start of statement (no modifiers allowed here)  ChecksumAcc.sc  /HelloWorld/src line 3  Scala Problem`

basically complains about `private`

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object ChecksumAcc {
    private val cache = Map[String, Int]()

}
```

I'm using Eclipse for Scala worksheet. Same after updating. I believe it uses 2.9.3 scala compiler. Why doesn't it compile?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what your actual question is, but the Scala worksheet has some special rules (as indicated by the very clear error message...). One thing you can do if you **have** to use the worksheet, is to put all your code inside a `Worksheet` object like this:

```
object Worksheet {
  import scala.collection.mutable.Map

  object ChecksumAcc {
    private val cache = Map[String, Int]()
  }
}
```

Or alternatively, use Eclipse's "New Scala object..." and use that instead of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error message you are seeing, when you are working in a Eclipse Scala work sheet
wrap the Class definition and Companion class (Singleton object) in the same object

```
object worksheet { 
 class CheckSumAccumulator {
 ... 
 } 
  object CheckSumAccumulator { 
  ... 
  } 
  CheckSumAccumulator.calculate("foobar")

}
```